# Cant get a working jsfiddle to work when I copy over to my computer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsfiddle

When I click on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RQL5V/ everything is working properly.
However, when I attempt to copy the code over to Dreamweaver(html file) via http://jsfiddle.net/RQL5V/show/ and deploy, the page seems to freeze up and when the links are clicked and drop down is supposed to be displayed nothing happens...

I cant get this to work not matter what I try!

any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<p>Thanks!</p>
```

Comment: Did you also include the external libraries (JQuery) in your local HTML document?

Comment: @CarloCannas i included this <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">

Comment: @CarloCannas I don't know what I am missing. the code on this page http://jsfiddle.net/RQL5V/show/ should be the entirety of the code right? if not what do I add and where?

Comment: Are you loading the document in your browser by a `file:` URL? If it's so, that's the problem.

Comment: Are you waiting for the window to load before running your code, just like you are in the fiddle? (please provide relevant code in your question, `<p>Thanks!</p>` isn't very helpful.)

Comment: @CarloCannas your answer seems to be correct. once I published the website and viewed the code online it is working properly... Is there a way to fix the code to view via file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you can't simply copy the code, since there are some relative URLs. Specifically `//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js` is the problem, it's a relative URL made to be short and work both in HTTP or HTTPS. If you use the absolute URL `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js` it should work.

When working on a document loaded by a `file:` URL, the above relative path would be resolved into `file://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js`.